# Коснулся первый объект второго? Как узнать? Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Код сейчас:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root, width=700, height=700)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(50, 2, 90, 10, 10, 10,
                      fill='red',
                      outline='black')
def movetriangle(event):
    if event.keysym=='Up':
        canvas.move(1, 0, -3)
    elif event.keysym=='Down':
        canvas.move(1, 0, 3)
    elif event.keysym=='Left':
        canvas.move(1, -7, 0)
    elif event.keysym=='Right':
        canvas.move(1, 7, 0)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', movetriangle)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Down>', movetriangle)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', movetriangle)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', movetriangle)
root.mainloop()
```

Сейчас есть только один объект. А если добавить второй. Как узнать коснулся ли первый объект второго? А если второй объект коснулся стены, как это узнать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `Canvas` есть метод `find_overlapping`, который находит все объекты, попадающие в заданный прямоугольник. Мы можем как первое приближение "заменить" первую фигуру на прямоугольник, найти пересекающиеся с этим прямоугольником фигуры - так мы найдем фигуры, которые возможно пересекаются с данной фигурой и отсечем фигуры, которые точно не пересекаются с ней.

В коде будет что-то вроде этого:

```
poly1 = canvas.create_polygon(50, 2, 90, 10, 10, 10, fill='red', outline='black')

...
# Получаем множество возможно пересекающихся фигур:
overlapping = set(canvas.find_overlapping(*canvas.bbox(poly1)))
# canvas.bbox(poly1) - получить ограничивающий прямоугольник (bounding box) указанной фигуры

# В множество пересекающихся фигур попадает сама исходная фигура, удаляем ее из множества:
overlapping.discard(poly1)
```

Дальше уже нужно использовать более точные методы - например проверять, есть ли пересекающиеся стороны двух фигур.

Рекомендую почитать книгу "Физика для разработчиков компьютерных игр" (Д.Конгер), конкретно главу про обнаружение столкновений.

По поводу столкновения со стеной - это довольно просто проверяется, просто проверяете, не вышел ли какой-то из углов за границы допустимой области.

Comment: Спасибо!        .........